# Obtener valor de una función async en js y Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, promesas, async-await

he estado trabajando con javascript para hacer solicitudes con axios para un componente de vue, tengo un archivo js con la siguiente estructura:

```
import axios from 'axios/dist/axios'

import env from '../environments/environment.js';


var cita={

    get_user: async function(){

        let url_bases = env.url_base;

        try{
            // Consultamos la cita
            const data = await axios(url_bases+'/cliente/get-por-id/1')

            return data

        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

}

export default cita;
```

El principal problema es que en el componente necesito obtener el valor de lo que retorna cita.get_user() pero en pantalla me dice [object promise], este es el componente:

```
import login_component from "@/Login/login_component";

    import script from '../scripts/ejemplo1.js';

    // Servicios
    import cita from '../servicios/cita.js';

    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        components:{
            login_component
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
              c:this.mensaje,
              guillermo:[]
            }
        },
        methods:{
            get_client(){
                this.guillermo=cita.get_user()
            }
        },
        created(){
           this.get_client()
        }
    };
```

Si alguien sabe, quedaría sumamente agradecido

Comment: No has resuelto esa promesa, ¿nos muestras como la procesas en tu vista o donde sea que la usas?

Comment: Trata con `beforeMount` ahi llamas la funcion de los datos y llamas a `then` para cuando tengas el resultado lo asignes al componente.

Comment: El valor que muestro desde el componente es la variable guillermo, solamente la muestro en la vista con {{}}, pero se supone que con await el valor de la promesa queda como valor y no como una promesa como tal no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas `debugger;` o imprimes console.logs antes de llamar `this.guillermo=cita.get_user()` antes de consultar la data, antes de retornar el valor de la data y antes de asignar el valor retornado te daras cuenta que se asigna el valor retornado antes de que termina de obtener la data. Lo que pasa es que aunque tu funcion cita sabe que debes esperar para que axios devuelva la data, la funcion `get_client` no sabe que `cita.get_user()` tiene que esperar.

Si usas async/await o then en get_client deberia funcionar

```
methods:{
    async get_client(){
        this.guillermo= await cita.get_user()
    }
},
```

PD: No tienes que wrapper el objeto del servicio en un var

```
import axios from 'axios/dist/axios';
import env from '../environments/environment.js';

async function get_user() {
    let url_bases = env.url_base;
    try{
        // Consultamos la cita
        const data = await axios(url_bases+'/cliente/get-por-id/1')
        return data;
    } catch (error) { 
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export default {
  get_user
};
```

Comment: Perfecto funciona correctamente, no estaba haciendo el async/await en el método del componente, muchas gracias !!!